# Accessing nested structs in C# with LayoutKind.Explicit

Tags: c#, pointers, struct, pinvoke, shared-memory

I have an application in C# that needs to share some binary data with Python, and I'm planning to use shared memory (memory mapped file). Thus, I need to have the same binary structure on both sides.

I create a struct in C# (`ST_Layer`) that has an array of items of another struct (`ST_Point`). To access those items I have defined a function `getPoint` that will return a pointer to the position of the requested `ST_Point`.

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

class TestProgram
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 8)]
    public struct ST_Point
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)] public double X;
        [FieldOffset(8)] public double Y;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 8)]
    public unsafe struct ST_Layer
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)] public ushort nPoints;
        [FieldOffset(8)] public double fHeight;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10)]
        [FieldOffset(16)] public ST_Point[] Points;

        public unsafe ST_Point* getPoint(int n)
        {
            fixed (ST_Layer* thisPtr = &this)
            {
                int ptr = (int)&(thisPtr->Points) + n * ((16 + 3) / 4) * 4;   // Sizeof ST_Point 16
                return (ST_Point*)ptr;
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        unsafe
        {
            ST_Layer layer = new ST_Layer();
            layer.nPoints = 3;
            layer.fHeight = 4;
            layer.getPoint(0)->X = 5;
            layer.getPoint(3)->Y = 6;

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                Debug.WriteLine("Data [" + i + "] " + layer.getPoint(i)->X + ", " + layer.getPoint(i)->Y + " - ");
            while (true)
                Thread.Sleep(50);
        }
    }
}
```

I have 2 questions:

- The previous code works if I compile the code for x86, but not for x64 or 'Any CPU' ('System.AccessViolationException' exception in 'layer.getPoint(0)->X'). Is it an expected behaviour? What can I do to solve this exception?
- I'm using the `getPoint` function to access the `ST_Point` array because I have not seen a better way of accessing it. Is it possible to access it as a normal array (i.e. `layer.Points[0].X`)? I can't create the array of `ST_Point` (`layer.Points = new ST_Point[10]`), as it'll be created outside the `ST_Layer`, and data will not be passed to Python.

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168658/accommodating-nested-unsafe-structs-in-c-sharp) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309838/improper-marshaling-c-sharp-array-to-a-c-unmanaged-array), but don't know how to access the individual fields of `ST_Point`.

Thank you for your help.

[Also, thank you R. Martinho Fernandes for your [hint regarding the x86/x64 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18252141/3744282)]

Comment: You realize that the pointer returned from `getPoint` is (may be) immediately invalid? `fixed` only works for things textually inside it.

Comment: @GSerg, you may be right (you're right), but the solution seems to be working. Isn't the returned pointer correct?

Comment: None of this code does what you think it does. Unsafe `fixed` is not designed to return a pointer out of it, the fact the pointer doesn't move doesn't mean it won't move in the future. `MarshalAs` doesn't work unless you are actually marshalling. I suggest you use `MemoryMappedFile` instead, which is exactly designed for your use case.

Comment: @Charlieface, I'm actually using `MemoryMappedFile`, but then I have to assign that memory to a struct, and that's where I find the problem.
`        using (var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen("SharedMemory", Marshal.SizeOf<ST_Layer>()))
        {
            unsafe
            {
                using (var accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor())
                {
                    byte* sharedMemPtr = null;
                    accessor.SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle.AcquirePointer(ref sharedMemPtr);
                    ST_Layer* layer = (ST_Layer*)sharedMemPtr;`

Comment: So why aren't you just using [`accessor.Read<ST_Layer>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.unmanagedmemoryaccessor.read?view=net-8.0#system-io-unmanagedmemoryaccessor-read-1(system-int64-0@)) to copy in and out, why are you messing with pointers? You can't expect a managed struct to correctly work with an unsafe pointer, you need to marshal it. Only if it's an `unmanaged struct` can you use a pointer without marshalling, and only if the pointer is pinned.

Comment: @Charlieface, thanks for your comment. I see your solution is similar to the one from MatthewWatson. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Well he's added the `InlineArray` which means there is less marshalling overhead. But either way you don't need `unsafe`, I was just trying to understand why you made it so unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: @Charlieface, please check my last comment in Matthew's answer: I prefer not to do  `Read()` and  `Write()` with every data change. However, I may think again about it, as  `unsafe` is clearly not best practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a recent version of .NET you can use [`System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InlineArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-12.0/inline-arrays) to read and write the struct directly from and to the MMF, without any unsafe code.

The `InlineArray` attribute allows you to specify a struct which contains a fixed number of elements of a specific value type, which can be accessed via an indexing operation:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Console1;

public static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("MappedFile", 1000);

        var view = mmf.CreateViewAccessor();

        using UnmanagedMemoryAccessor accessor = view;

        var s = new ST_Layer();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            s.Points[i] = new ST_Point { X = i, Y = -i };
        }

        long offset = 500; // Arbitrary offset with the MMF.

        view.Write(offset, ref s);

        view.Read(offset, out ST_Layer t);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{t.Points[i].X}, {t.Points[i].Y}");
        }
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct ST_Point
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public double X;
    [FieldOffset(8)] public double Y;
}

// This is the crucial bit: Define a fixed inline array with 10 elements:
[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InlineArray(10)]
public struct TenPoints
{
    ST_Point _firstElement;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public ushort nPoints;
    [FieldOffset(8)] public double fHeight;
    [FieldOffset(16)] public TenPoints Points;
}
```

Comment: The [docs say](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.pack?view=net-8.0#remarks) `Pack` doesn't affect `struct`s with `LayoutKind.Explicit`.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride That's true, you choose one or the other. I was just copying what the OP had.  I've removed the Pack attributes to avoid confusion.

Comment: @MatthewWatson, thank you for your help. However, in your solution, you still need to call `view.Write()` or `view.Read()` in order to update the shared data. If you replace `var s = new ST_Layer()` with a pointer to the shared memory (`byte* sharedMemPtr = null;view.SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle.AcquirePointer(ref sharedMemPtr);ST_Layer* s = (ST_Layer*)sharedMemPtr;`), you can now access the data directly `s->Points[]`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I forgot to add that the pointer solution (`view.SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle.AcquirePointer(ref sharedMemPtr)`) needs unsafe.

Comment: @Asier Why do you need to use the pointer solution? The correct approach is to use `view.Read()` and `view.Write()`. The difference in speed will be negligible, and you won't need unsafe code.

Comment: @MatthewWatson, I prefer the pointer solution. Using `Read()` and  `Write()` requires to call them every time a value is changed (the actual struct is bigger that the one shown here). Besides, if both programs are doing RW of the data, changing a value would require a semaphore, calling `Read()`, then changing the single value and finally calling `Write()`

Comment: "Besides, if both programs are doing RW of the data, changing a value would require a semaphore, calling Read(), then changing the single value and finally calling Write()" You'd also need a semaphore (or similar) when changing data via a pointer - how else would the other end know you've changed the data? Also it looks like you'd need interprocess locking in order to prevent reading of partially updated data.

Comment: The other side would just read the new value whenever it needs it. Each one of the programs updates different variables, even if they are related. Regarding the prevention of partially updated data, yes, I need to control it, but it only happens in a few places and they are currently being managed.

Comment: "The other side would just read the new value whenever it needs it" What if it's reading a point just when the other side had updated X but not Y? Then it would be reading bad data (equivalent of a torn read).

Comment: Regarding the prevention of partially updated data, those bits of data are controlled and already managed in the working solution. This new solution is an update/upgrade of the existing one, which doesn't have need that C#/Python communication. Thank you very much for your help.